# Zoom (openlayers)

Tags: zooming, openlayers, tile

As for the current version, I have not found a proper way to detect the zoom start (without overriding the animation function). In my case both **movestart** and **moveend** events does not solve the problem.

The actual need for the zoom start is the TileWMS layer. I need to set it to invisible on certain zoom levels. This cannot be set on move end, because at move end the layer still loads tiles from geoserver although set to invisible. Enable / disable property is also not available on the layer itself.

Setting the layer invisible on **movestart** solves the problem with fetching but on drag already loaded the tiles are not visible :) this is annoying for the user experience.

Is there any other idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: You could use the view's `change:resolution` event

Comment: Technically setting invisible on certain layer, will only do you one request. I dont think there is a way to catch zoom start, since its kind of unexpected input. Id stick to zoom end, on certain level your layer will be invisible and then it wont do further requests.

Comment: The problem is that we have 10mio. points or more in the database, so higher level can take sometimes more than 30 seconds to render the tiles. Sure after that the cache is built but initially it looks like map do not show tiles... And during this time the geoserver is blocked by doing the tile rending.